# Proving that $\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\int_{\mu}^{\infty}t^{r-1}e^{-t}dt=\sum_{x=0}^{r-1}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^x}{x!}$

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\int_{\mu}^{\infty}t^{r-1}e^{-t}dt=\sum_{x=0}^{r-1}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^x}{x!}$$
What I have tried-

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\int_{\mu}^{\infty}t^{r-1}e^{-t}dt=e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=0}^{r-1}\frac{\mu^x}{x!}$$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)}\int_{\mu}^{\infty}t^{r-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nt^n}{n!}dt=e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=0}^{r-1}\frac{\mu^x}{x!}$$

But I tried interchanging the sum and the integral and it didn't make sense anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you recognize the Poisson probability terms in the sum? [Have a look here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312549/story-proof-relating-poisson-and-gamma)   And please:   Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467341/321264 and its linked threads.

Comment: You can find more closely related threads [with this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+poisson+gamma+distribution+score%3A2+-regression).